# how to manipulate fields of Serializer without changing the model?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have the following serializer in serializers.py:

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id','subject')
```

I want to parser the subject and serialize 2 other fields instead the original field "subject" - subject1 = foo1(subject) and subject2 = foo2(subject)
so the former class Meta will become:

```
Class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = ('id','subject1','subject2')
```

Please pay attention I don't want to change the Message model itself (which can be done be @property definition)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [SerializerMethodField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield) assuming its read-only.  If you need read-write, you'll have to write a custom Serializer Field.